# Path aliases more than one

Tags: path-aliases

I could explain everything, but that will take me a while, so, long story short.

I need one node to have 2 path alises (Not re-direction) 2 path aliases, and this is what I need to do, to show some fields in my view or hide them.

The idea is if I access from one view I need to show some fields, or If I join from another one I should hide it

Answer (score 1):

Its not good idea to have one page or node with 2 different url, what i suggest to you is to override node view page with panel and create 2 variants.

Create the 2 different views panes and drop them each one in variant.

In the link to that node add GET variabile and switch the right variant based on that

Example
/my-url will show the first variat
/my-ulr?show=1
Will show the second variant

You control that with panel visibility rule and use php code to check the $_GET array